# jQuery: chaining of multiple child elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a parent element with multiple children each which require different changes. There's an easy solution, but I'm wondering whether chaining is possible and would be more efficient.

A very simple example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>

----------------------

$('#parent .one').text('Some');
$('#parent .two').text('Thing');
$('#parent .three').text('Else');
```

Is there a way to do something similar to this?

```
$('#parent')
  .children('.one').text('Some')
  .children('.two').text('Thing')
  .children('.three').text('Else');
```

Where each child resets the chain back to the parent. Also, would this be efficient other than making the code easier to read? Remember, this is a very simple example to clarify the question. I'm not referring to this exact code. I really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) will return the chain to what it was before the last filtering :

```
$('#parent')
  .children('.one').text('Some').end()
  .children('.two').text('Thing').end()
  .children('.three').text('Else');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#parent')
    .find('.one').text('Some')
    .siblings('.two').text('Thing')
    .siblings('.three').text('Else');
```

Comment: This will work in OPs example, but assumes items will always be "ordered", which might not be always true

Comment: true... you can always replace 'next' with 'siblings' in that case though.